# An answer got accepted absurdly rapidly (Never mind, it was a proxy user troll)

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

https://music.stackexchange.com/q/84207/45266 is the question at hand here.

Great question (it too is in response to another question, interestingly), and I took the time to offer my opinion in the form of an answer.

Another user answered as I was just finishing up my answer, and our answers had different content. I was snaked by about a minute, probably less than 60 seconds. I'm fine with that, since our answers are different, and I feel the merit of my answer remains unblemished by its tardiness. Plus, the other answerer had some great points too.

My problem is this:

[image: Snaked!!!]

Yep, you read that correctly. **One minute after the answer was posted, OP had already accepted it.**

Nobody on this planet can possibly convince me that in less than 60 seconds, OP decided that this answer was the *best possible answer*, better than all future answers, or in some way helped OP personally in a way that others could not outdo.

I've read Meta posts about when answers should be accepted, and I just can't believe that the other answer fits those descriptions. Sure, it's a good answer, and I even upvoted it. But the timing of the accept by OP is not appropriate, in my opinion.

I asked OP themself in the comments to consider waiting, and OP responded to the effect of playing it off as a joke, if I'm not misunderstanding OP here. I know OP is a new user, and already has some content here on this site that I'd expect from seasoned users here. The kind of user this site welcomes, as far as I can tell. I'd hate to lose them over this issue.

What can I do to try to reason with OP or improve my competition? Or am I being unreasonable here? What should I be doing? Site "case law"?

Also, let it be known that I'm not arguing that I deserve the accept, or that the other user does not. I've no problem with the accepted content, but I decry OP accepting it so soon.

---

### **EDIT: Mystery solved. The OP was in fact a proxy user for one of our currently suspended users, and thus the question has been deleted, along with that user.**

Comment: I am suspicious that this new user is in fact a reincarnation of the recently suspended Maika Sakuranomiya.

Comment: @DavidBowling Whoa! How suspicious! Wow, I never would have suspected! I'll flag some of this for the mods. It would all make sense; this user seems to only post on threads that Maika wrote, and was created just after the suspension took effect... Very similar writing style, too. Wow, great sleuthing if that turns out to be the case! I'm amazed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be confusing for users who stumble onto this post, but yes there was some fishy business on this account and it was tied to Maika who was recently suspended. The new user has been deleted and all content created by the account was deleted/destroyed including the question under examination here.

If we really want to we can undelete the question itself since people did put in time to answer the question, but I feel it's better in the long term to just get rid of content generated though this odd set of circumstances.

Comment: I completely agree. I was planning to delete my answer anyway if it turned out to be true (of course that's the one where I get "nice answer"!) :P

Comment: @user45266 -- it stinks that you lost a "nice answer" over this, and that is one of the insidious harms of sock-puppet accounts: they get other users entangled in some bad actor's abuse of the system. You have certainly been walking the high road with this and the earlier reporting of suspected serial _upvoting_. Chin up.

Comment: @DavidBowling Haha, thanks. I'm very impressed that you figured this proxy account out! I love me some shinies (badges), but there'll be plenty more questions to answer here. Besides, I think most users recognise the evils of V(no3 no5)!